# json object with nested objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

If you have the below:

```
var test = '{"0":"1", "2":"3"}';
```

if produces object 0: 1   2: 3

How do I create a object with like object: object: 0: 1 2: 3   object: 4: 5 6: 7

I have tried:

```
var test = '[{"0":"1", "2":"3"}]';
```

or

```
var test = '{"0": {"0":"1", "2":"3"}}';
```

Comment: i don't understand what you want exaclty, your pseudo code doesn't help much and btw your test variable doesn't produce what you say it produces, it is a string, so what are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using strings instead of JSON. You can simply use `{}` to define objects and `[]` to define arrays and `"key" : value` syntax for key-value pairs.

```
var objA = { "0": "1", "2": "3" };
var objB = { "4": "5", "6": "7" };

var test = { "0": objA, "1": objB };
```

or in one line

```
var test = { "0": { "0": "1", "2": "3" }, "1": { "4": "5", "6": "7" } };
```

If you need to parse JSON strings then you can use

```
var test = JSON.parse('{ "0": { "0": "1", "2": "3" }, "1": { "4": "5", "6": "7" } }');
```

Comment: This is a nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

Just create an array. And push the object into an array.

```
var obj = {};
    obj["0"] = "1";
    obj["2"] = "3";

var wObj = {};
    wObj["0"] = obj;
console.log(wObj);
```

This is nested object example. **[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/MsEQC/)**

2nd Example `object` inside an array

```
var obj = {};
    obj["0"] = "1";
    obj["2"] = "3";

var wObj = [];

wObj.push(obj);
console.log(wObj);
```

**[Array Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/MsEQC/1/)**

Comment: Could you give an example

Comment: Can you build the same thing in a single string I am going to use JSON.parse to make the string in to a nested object set

Comment: Your string should be in the form of Array of objects `[{"0":"1"}, {"2":"3"}]; `

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
var test = '[{"0":"1", "2":"3"}, {"0":"3", "1":"2"}]'
```

`{"0":"1", "2":"3"}` Is your first object

`{"0":"3", "1":"2"}` Is your second

All encapsulated in one array.

Comment: here test is a string

Comment: But why are you wrapping it in quotes?

Comment: That worked!! I swear I tried that exact same setup must have had a syntax error in mine. Ill give you a green check in 6 minutes ><

Comment: @MikeOltmans could you provide a sample of what 'it works' because here doesn't make sense at all!...

Comment: @roasted: Well the array with 2 objects should work, but the question was misleading asking for JSON object with nested objects.

Comment: @Ma3x so OP is parsing it to JSON, that's ok but why not creating directly a valid JSON object? I must missing something here.

Comment: it starts out as part of a input onclick event parameter created by a php statement which means I can't create an object only a string.

Comment: You can always call a function which does it!